# hide div on blur event of hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html

this is the html code

```
<a class="button_example" onclick="funshow()" onblur="hide()">login</a>
```

here is the jquery code

```
function funshow() {
        $(".logbox").toggle();

    }

 function hide() {            
        $(".logbox").toggle();
    }
```

**when i click on the hyperlink it show the div
but when i click another part of the body it does not hide..
so how do i can hide the div on blur 
please  help.**

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function funshow() {
    $(".logbox").show();
}

function hide() {            
    $(".logbox").hide();
}
```

Or try simply like,

**HTML**

```
<a class="button_example" href="#">login</a>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.button_example').on({
     'click': function () {
         $(".logbox").show();
     },
     'blur': function () {
         $(".logbox").hide();
     }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X2PER/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
  $('.button_example').on({
     'click': function () {
     $(".logbox").show();
 }
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".logbox");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post the jquery plugin link

Answer (score 0):

The problem in above scenario is that events onfocus and onblur doesnot work for link
1. You can use onmouseout event instead of blur for hiding the  .logbox but this will hide it if mouse is not on link 
 **OR**
2. If you are not redirecting user to any other page using hyperlink then instead of link use a button and apply css so that it will look like a link

```
<button onclick="funshow()" onblur="hide()">login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="button_example">login</a>
<div class="logbox">gfsdfgfd</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
                 $('.button_example').click(function() {
                       $(".logbox").toggle();
                       });

               });
```